# How to access short URl from Json object in c# - Bitly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, bitly

I am using Bitly api in Asp.net project to create short Url. I am getting result but it is in json format. How do I retrieve short Url from it?

```html
[HttpGet("sendNotification/{PlanId}")]
        [ValidateModelState]
        public async Task<IActionResult> SendNotification()
        {
                var link ="https://chats.landbot.io";
                var shortUrl = await GetShortUrl(link);
              
                return NoContent();
            }
            
        }
```

shortUrl giving me everything as below

```html
{"created_at":"2021-10-21T04:01:53+0000","id":"bit.ly/shortUrl","link":"LongUrl","archived":false,"tags":[],"deeplinks":[],"references":{"group":"https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v4"}}
```

In the above line, id contains the Short link and that's the only link I need.
Can anyone tell me what I should do?

Comment: Can you share your  `GetShortUrl`?What is the return type of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.JObject:

```
{{"created_at":"2021-10-21T04:01:53+0000","id":"bit.ly/shortUrl","link":"LongUrl","archived":false,"tags":[],"deeplinks":[],"references":{"group":"https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v4"}}}
```

If you want to get `id`from JObject,you can use:

```
var id=jObject["id"].Tostring;
```

2.json string:

```
{\"created_at\":\"2021-10-21T04:01:53+0000\",\"id\":\"bit.ly/shortUrl\",\"link\":\"LongUrl\",\"archived\":false,\"tags\":[],\"deeplinks\":[],\"references\":{\"group\":\"https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v4\"}}
```

If you want to get `id` from json string,you can use:

```
var id=JObject.Parse(jsonString)["id"].Tostring;
```

Answer (score 0):

Create class like below

```
public class Item
 {
    public string created_at;
    public string id;
    public string link;
  }
```

And in your method read json string like below code using newtonsoft json
In items you will get the values.

```
Item items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Item>(json);
```